# Is the matrix $A$ diagonalizable if $A^2=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is an involutory matrix, i.e. $A^2=I$, then is $A$ diagonalizable?

Comment: Using Representation theory one can show that every complex matrix of finite order is diagonalisable.

Comment: @Benjamin: Or just using the same argument: if $A^n=I$, then $A$ satisfies $t^n-1$, which has $n$ distinct roots over $\mathbb{C}$; hence the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ has no repeated roots, and hence $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You said it slicker than me. I was thinking Maschke's Theorem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since $A^2=I$, then $A$ satisfies the polynomial $t^2-1 = (t-1)(t+1)$. Hence, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(t-1)(t+1)$; so the minimal polynomial of $A$ splits and has distinct roots, so $A$ is diagonalizable.

---

As N.S. points out in the comments, the above fails if you are working in characteristic 2. There, the matrix
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$$
has minimal and characteristic polynomials $t^2+1 = (t+1)^2$, and it is not diagonalizable (the eigenspace of $1$ has dimension $1$). But if $1\neq -1$, you are set.

Comment: Unless you are in characteristic 2 ;)

Comment: Thanks! Nice and simple answer.

Comment: @N.S. Ah, true.